# Can WSL git be used with the IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, intellij-plugin

Can WSL git be used with the IntelliJ IDE?

If it is possible, how would one construct the path to WSL's git executable, or is there better integration method (plugin, third party app, etc.)?

Comment: Why not use the Windows client for Git or Tortoise Git for the IDE? You can still use Git under WSL for command-line stuff. That's what I do, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [no official solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172253) at the moment, but you can try [this workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197573#focus=streamItem-27-3866974.0-0).

Another option would be to run IDE itself inside WSL by installing the X Window Server and configuring the `DISPLAY` environment. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/993331/9280) for more details.

Comment: UPDATE: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/06/intellij-idea-2020-2-eap3-support-for-git-installed-in-wsl2-java-completion-improvements-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

You can also run IntelliJ IDEA inside WSL. It is possible, but UI will appear in the browser (Chrome or Firefox are supported). Follow instructions here: https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-server#not-modifying-your-application-code. As far as I know this project allows to run any Swing apps in headless mode in Linux with UI in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since IntelliJ 2020.2 Git in WSL2 is supported. You can set the path to, for example `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\git`, in Version Control->Git->Path to git Executable.